# Using Terminal/Command Line to Execute Python Notebook Shells on Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, google-colaboratory

I'm new to programming and I am using Google Colab to go through the exercises from "Learning Python the Hard Way".

I am stuck on exercise 13 as I need to run it using the command line (i.e. $ python3.6 ex13.py first 2nd 3rd).

So I would like to execute a code on a notebook cell using the Colab Terminal if possible.

If this is not possible, please suggest another way if you know any (for example, saving the code to a text file in google drive, and using the Terminal to execute the file). I'm not able to figure this out either.

This is where I'm stuck:

[Notebook Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP6ir.png)

And I would like to run this code using the Colab terminal (Here, I tried to save the file as a text file in Google Drive because I was not able to run the code on the Notebook cell using the command line):

[Colab Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LirVs.png)

[Python text file saved on Google Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ltgT.png)

Here is the code for your reference:

```
# p. 72 - Parameters, Unpacking, Variables
from sys import argv
# read the WYSS section for how to run this
script, first, second, third = argv

print("This script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)

#This is the command to execute the coder using command line: $ python3.6 ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
```

However, I would like to do this using Google Colab terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To execute in shell you can use `!` :

```bash
!python ex13.py aaa bbb ccc
```

Or `%%shell` magic:

```bash
%%shell
python ex13.py aaa bbb ccc
```

Though for this to work your *ex13.py* must by be in your working directory (or at least accessible) and this can be bit counter-intuitive:
your default working directory is not the location on your Google Drive where you have stored your Notebook (and *ex13.py*) , instead it's `/content` on Colab's temporary session storage.

So first you either upload your *ex13.py* to `/content` ( drag-and-drop from your local filesystem will do) or mount your GDrive to Colab (there's *Mount Drive* button)  and change your working directory to the location of your script with `%cd`, e.g. `%cd "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks"`

[Colab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O9iS.png)

Comment: Thank you! That worked. The screenshot in the answer really helped to work out the solution.

Comment: Just one more question. Is there a way to execute the command using the terminal? I am getting this error:

xercises# !python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
-bash: !python: event not found
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/Python_Exercises#

Comment: @Tanoj , try `python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd` , in terminal you don't need to add `!`, that's just for Colab code block.